# Does SSL/TLS communication require two public keys, one for CA and one for the server?

Tags: security, ssl, encryption, https, ssl-certificate

I've been reading about secure communication and am confused by the following. Please correct me if I'm wrong. It seems to me that the client would need two public keys to establish an SSL connection. The first is the public key of the CA used to verify their signature on the certificate sent by the server. That CA signature on the certificate was generated using the CA's private key and so the CA's public key is needed to verify it. The second is the public key of the server that is used to encrypt the symmetric shared key. The shared key is generated by the client and sent to the server to decrypt using the server's private key and so the server's public key is needed to encrypt it. Hence we need two different public keys. Is this correct? If so, does the certificate sent by the server contain two public keys?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about [IT security](https://security.stackexchange.com) rather than programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct, the client needs every public key in the chain.

> If so, does the certificate sent by the server contain two public keys?

The certificate sent by the server is usually not only one certificate, but a certificate-chain. Certificates are never signed by the root-certificate of an authority but by an intermediate certificate which is itself signed by the root-certificate or by other intermediate-certificates. The browser knows only about the root-certificate, so the server needs to send the whole chain leading to the root-certificate, otherwise there would be certificates missing in the chain and the servers certificate could not be verified to be signed by a trusted authority. Every certificate in this chain contains its own public key, so every certificate in the chain can be verified using the direct parents public key, until you verified the last certificate in the chain with the root-certificate which the browser is instructed to trust.

Answer (score 0):

You need more than the CA's public key. You need his own certificate. That's why a certificate *chain* is transmitted: except in the degenerate case of a self-signed certificate, this will consist of at least two certificates.

NB The server's public key is not 'used to encrypt the symmetric shared key'. The shared symmetric key is negotiated secretly and independently by both ends and never transmitted at all.

Comment: The working keys (plural) are _derived_ independently at both ends, but starting from the same inputs, and for plain-RSA the only nonpublic and thus secure input is the premaster secret which is RSA-encrypted from client to server.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Correct. But a premaster secret isn't a shared symmetric key.

Comment: I'd still say that the sentence "The shared symmetric key is negotiated secretly and independently by both ends and never transmitted at all." is simply wrong. Especially the word "independently" I would say is incorrect.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Then you would be wrong. It is negotiated; that process is secret and independent by definition; and it is never transmitted.

Comment: It is entirely possible to have a valid certificate chain consisting of a single *transmitted* certificate, signed by a trusted certificate. The chain is of course of length two.